# How do I display EXP gain when killing a creep?

Tags: league-of-legends

Whenever I watch YouTubers play League they have this gray text appearing telling them how much EXP they gain when they kill a creep. How do I enable that?

Answer (score 6):

Very easily!

Open up your settings either in-game by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, or by pressing the small cog wheel in the upper-right corner of the League of Legends client.

[image: Image of the League of Legends client, with the settings cog wheel circled in red]

Then, navigate to the **Interface** section on the left side of the Settings window. In the **Combat Text** subcategory, toggle on **Experience Gains**.

Here's a picture that indicates where this option is when out of game:

[image: Image of the settings window with the Interface window selected, and the "Experience Gains" option toggled on.]

When in-game, it's in the same categories, the display is just a bit different. Here's how that looks:

[image: Image of the in-game settings menu, opened up to the Interface submenu with the "Experience" option circled]

You will now see exp drops appear when you kill a minion/creep, like the following animated GIF showcases:

[image: Animated GIF of Zed with +exp notation after killing a minion]

Comment: This option also exists when you are in game.

Comment: I mentioned that in the first bit of my answer: *"Open up your settings either in-game by pressing Esc, **or** by pressing the small cog wheel in the upper-right corner of the League of Legends client."*